# How to conditionally add or remove element inside an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, conditional-operator

I don't want second element null in else condition .. i just don't want second element.
How to solve this issue?

```js
var template = "";
var myArray = [
  { element : "header" },
  template === 'foo' ? { element : "sidebar" } : null,
  { element : "footer" }
]
console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: Why are you putting a conditional statement in an array element?

Comment: I made you a snippet

Comment: how about `[...(template === 'foo' ? [{ element : "sidebar" }] : [])]` ?

Comment: Can you not use filter method once done ?
So `console.log(myArray.filter(Boolean))` will do the job;

Answer (score 8):

There something called conditional spread operator and it's perfect for your issue

When condition is false you spread empty array so literally nothing is added to array you declare

```js
const template1=""
const myArray1 = [
  { element : "header" },
  ...( template1 === 'foo' ? [{ element : "sidebar" }] : [] ),
  { element : "footer" }
]

console.log(myArray1)

const template2="foo"
const myArray2 = [
  { element : "header" },
  ...( template2 === 'foo' ? [{ element : "sidebar" }] : [] ),
  { element : "footer" }
]

console.log(myArray2)
```

Comment: Updated with an example

Comment: And some who like over-optimize everything can spread an empty string instead of an empty array (`...( template1 === 'foo' ? [{ element : "sidebar" }] : '' ),`), to avoid creating additional unused objects (but I don't know how many milliseconds or bytes of memory will it save)... +1

Comment: @FZs, interesting solution, never meet that approach. But don't you think it could be confusing for someone reading code? And there will be compile error in Typescript for example: `const a: number[] = [123, ...(true ? [123] : '')];` (you can try in playground)

Comment: @MarekSzkudelski I wouldn't use that, just mentioned *for some who like over-optimize everything* (excluding me). Performance optimizations in code often make its next reader confused...

Answer (score 2):

I like the spread operator in the other example

For compatibility, just use an if:

```js
var template1 = "foo";
var myArray1 = [
  { element : "header" },
  { element : "footer" }
]
if (template1 === 'foo') myArray1.splice(1,0,{ element : "sidebar" })
console.log(myArray1)


var template2 = "";
var myArray2 = [
  { element : "header" },
  { element : "footer" }
]
if (template2 === 'foo') myArray2.splice(1,0,{ element : "sidebar" })
console.log(myArray2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const template = '';
const myArray = [
  { element : "header" },
  { element : "footer" },
  ...(template === 'foo' ? [{ element : "sidebar" }] : [])
]
console.log(myArray)
```

You can spread a ternary condition inside the array, with an empty array as a falsy case.